# JS Vanilla Calculator - change operator

Tags: javascript, calculator

Currently building a simple calculator with vanilla JS.
All buttons and calculations work but i needed help with switching operators

When the user performs an operation it works just fine, but let's say the user pressed 2 and the  operator "+" instead of "-" like he wanted, so instead of clearing the screen he presses "-" right after (so "2" then "+" then "-"), the screen displays "NaN -" instead of just switching the operator.

How would I fix that?

```
let currentOperand = '';
let previousOperand = '';
let currentOperation = undefined;
let isEqualsPressed = false;


numberBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputNumber(btn.innerHTML)
    })
}) 

operationBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        isEqualsPressed = true;
        chooseOperation(btn.innerHTML)
    })
}) 

allClear.addEventListener('click', clear);
del.addEventListener('click', deleteLastNumber);
equals.addEventListener('click', evaluate);

function clear() {
    currentOperand = '';
    previousOperand = '';
    currentOperandScreen.textContent = '';
    previousOperandScreen.textContent = '';
    operator = undefined;
} 

function deleteLastNumber() {
    currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = currentOperandScreen.innerHTML.slice(0, -1)
} 

function inputNumber(number) {
    if(currentOperandScreen.innerHTML.includes(".") && number === ".") return;

    if(currentOperandScreen.innerHTML.length < 16)
    currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = (currentOperandScreen.innerHTML).toString() + number.toString();
} 

function chooseOperation (operator) {
    if (previousOperand !== '') {
        evaluate()
    }  
    previousOperand = currentOperandScreen.innerHTML;
    currentOperation = operator;
    currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = '';
    previousOperandScreen.innerHTML = `${previousOperand} ${operator}`;
}

function evaluate() {
    let result;
    previousOperand = parseFloat(previousOperand)
    currentOperand = parseFloat(currentOperandScreen.innerHTML);

    switch (currentOperation) {
        case "+":
            result = add(previousOperand, currentOperand);
            break;
        case "-":
            result = subtract(previousOperand, currentOperand);
            break;
        case "÷":
            if(currentOperand === 0) {
                result = "Error"
            } else
            {result = divide(previousOperand, currentOperand)};
            break;
        case "x":
            result = multiply(previousOperand, currentOperand);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    if (isEqualsPressed == true) {
        previousOperandScreen.innerHTML = `${previousOperand} ${currentOperation} ${currentOperand} =`
        currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = result;
    }

    currentOperand = result;
    currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = result;
    currentOperation = undefined;
    previousOperand = '';
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a condition in your `chooseOperation` function to check whether the `currentOperandScreen` has a value. If it doesn't, then the user is likely changing the operator.

```js
function chooseOperation (operator) {
   if(previousOperand !== '' && currentOperandScreen.innerHTML !== ''){
        currentOperation = operator
        return
   }else if (previousOperand !== '') {
        evaluate()
    }  
    previousOperand = currentOperandScreen.innerHTML;
    currentOperation = operator;
    currentOperandScreen.innerHTML = '';
    previousOperandScreen.innerHTML = `${previousOperand} ${operator}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a judgment mark "isOperation" between each click on operationBtns, similar to throttling

```js
let currentOperand = '';
let previousOperand = '';
let currentOperation = undefined;
let isEqualsPressed = false;
let isOperation = false

numberBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputNumber(btn.innerHTML)
        isOperation = true
    })
}) 

operationBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        isEqualsPressed = true;
        if(isOperation){
             chooseOperation(btn.innerHTML)
        }
        isOperation = false
    })
})
```

Or there are other methods, such as determining that the input character and the data type of the last character displayed on the page are both strings and do not do so

I hope my answer can help you